# Yocto: package requires shared library but no providers found in RDEPENDS_?

Tags: package, shared-libraries, embedded-linux, yocto

I have designed an application composed from a main program `core` who calls a shared library `dio.so`, these are the 2 recipes I wrote:

1- core.bb:

```
#
# This file was derived from the 'Hello World!' example recipe in the
# Yocto Project Development Manual. 
#

SUMMARY = "Core "
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://* "
      
S = "${WORKDIR}/sources"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake STAGING_PATH=${STAGING_DIR}
}

do_install() {
    oe_runmake install IMAGE_PATH=${D}
}

DEPENDS += "libdio"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libdio"
```

2- dio.bb:

```
#
# This file was derived from the 'Hello World!' example recipe in the
# Yocto Project Development Manual. 
#

SUMMARY = "DIO"
SECTION = "examples"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"
PN = "dio"

SRC_URI = "file://* "
      
S = "${WORKDIR}/sources"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
    oe_runmake install IMAGE_PATH=${D} STAGING_PATH=${STAGING_DIR}
}

PROVIDES = "libdio"
RPROVIDES_${PN} = "libdio"
```

`do_compile`, `do_install` and do_package`` are succesful for both of the recipes, but the problem is on `do_package_qa`for core, it throws the following error:

```
bitbake -c do_package_qa core
core-1.0-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/bin/core contained in package core requires libdio.so()(64bit), but no providers found in RDEPENDS_core? [file-rdeps]
```

As you can see I added the following to handle the dependency but it seems that something is missing, changing `libdio` with `dio` didn't solve the problem as well, any hint or Idea on fixing the problem ?

```
#dio.bb
PROVIDES = "libdio"
RPROVIDES_${PN} = "libdio"

#core.bb
DEPENDS += "libdio"
RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libdio"
```

Comment: First, don't use `*` in `SRC_URI`, it does NOT work, globbing isn't supported. Yes, I know "but it works", no it does not because your files aren't watched by Yocto so any change to a file in `SRC_URI` will not be caught by the build system and you will scratch your head trying to understand why (been there, done that).

Comment: Then, you should actually create versioned libraries (.so.x.y) and not unversioned libraries (.so). This is best practice and almost a requirement in Yocto. The only "accepted" exception is for pre-built libraries. You should also check which package is creating the non-versioned library, with `oe-pkgdata-util find-path '*libdio.so*'`. This will tell you if a package actually provides this library. If not, you have a bigger issue. If there is one that isn't `libdio`, it's probably the -dev package and it's expected as by default non-versioned libraries are put into the -dev package.

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the problem by adding following lines:

```
#core.bb
DEPENDS += " libdio"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += " libdio.so()(64bit)"

#dio.bb
PROVIDES = " libdio"
RPROVIDES_${PN} += " libdio.so()(64bit)"
```

So I just used the same name in the error message, from where comes these names ? I don't know, but at least it works now

Comment: This is a bad solution as it only will work if the library's `${PN}-dev` packages are installed on the target machine.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the shared state cache stores the old version of libraries.
Try to clean the cache and build again:

```
bitbake <yourapp> -c cleansstate
bitbake <yourapp>
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe there is a missing whitespace:

RPROVIDES_${PN} = " libdio"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = " libdio"